# UL cert question

Tags: certification, ul

We build large machinery which we require UL, CE and several other marks for shipping globally. Does using components that are not UL certified preclude us from getting these certs or do the components not matter as long as we pass the machine as a whole?

Comment: what are you going to do with the answer?

Comment: I don't think it's really relevant with the forum, it's more a UL regulation issue than electronic design

Comment: UL is not a self-certification. Generally if you have to ask...

Answer (score 1):

For UL, you need to have y a laboratory to check the UL compliance and issue a certificate. For the components, they don't necessarily need to be all UL compliant but if you have things like Relay, Breaker, Plug, Socket, it better is.

Since you need to have it certified, it is better to ask the certification body about the compliance before you send your product for review.

For CE it's a bit easier as you most of the time only need a declaration of conformity issued by the company, although if it's not compliant the company will be legally responsible for damage, so you may also want to have it certified.

Answer (score 1):

*Generally* speaking UL listed components will make the UL certification allot simpler and cheaper, as you *typically* can refer to the testing performed on the UL listed part (instead of doing it yourself)

On the flip side UL listed parts may have limited availability and high cost, so you might want to look into the added cost of performing the required tests vs using a more expensive component.

But there are literally thousands of if's and but's here. Talk to your UL rep. Involve UL in part selection. It will save you allot of time and money if you make informed choices *early* instead of showing up on their doorstep with a product that cannot be certified.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anybody's parts in a UL listed item. **You will just have to pay UL to certify those parts**.  This involves a lot of cooperation from the factory, since UL inspectors will now be onsite. If their normal output is Alibaba tier cheapies, they will need to use different design, tooling and feedstocks to hit the UL marks.

This also marries you to that one supplier.

When you select RU-Recognized parts (UL's component mark) it means UL will simply "give a wave" to those parts and you won't have to pay for component cert also.  For low-volume production, that really seems like the way to go.

As discussed, you really need to be "thinking about UL cert" from the moment this thing becomes a back-of-napkin drawing.  We see *lots and lots* of equipment builders focus on "building a better mousetrap" and completely ignore the UL White Book, then expect to get a UL listing as a bolt-on at the very end. Then they find their very design was flawed, clear back to the napkin.

A classic example is home power monitors. The competition sticks an electronic module inside the home service panel/consumer unit, with CTs and everything inside, and nothing but a WiFi antenna poking out.  Joe Blow is sketching on a bar napkin, sees a market opening: move the module outside the panel and fit a nice display and ethernet port so you can extract raw data. Just run a bundle of CTs from the head unit into the panel.  Finish it, build prototypes, then talk to UL as an afterthought.  Surprise: **what makes their product special *is illegal***. Any possible installation instructions will instruct the user to violate NEC. Since *approval of labeling and instructions* is part of a UL Listing, the item can never be UL listed.  This should have been caught at the napkin phase, but this person was a data acquisition wonk, not a Code wonk.